# Qt QTreeView Check if a selected folder is expanded and achieving treeview navigation

Tags: qt, treeview

I want to implement manual controls to a QTreeView object in Qt. (That means there will be programmatical control of everything, including navigation) So far I've implemented navigating / selecting in siblings. However, I want to establish a state where it is easier to control, whether there are expanded folders or not. If there is no such approach implemented in the Qt API, I'm going to have to know if a selected Folder item is expanded or not.

For example, for checking if an item is a folder, I check my directory model and do a string comparison (I know this is not the best way, but I dont know if Qt API features this also):

```
int MainWindow::checkIfFolder_treeview (void)
{
    /* Check if highlighted item is a folder by checking type name*/
    QModelIndex index_foldersearch = ui->treeView->currentIndex().sibling(ui->treeView->currentIndex().row(), 2);
    QVariant data_foldersearch = ui->treeView->model()->data(index_foldersearch);
    //qDebug() << "typeName:" << data_foldersearch.toString();
    if (QString::compare("Folder", data_foldersearch.toString()) == 0)
    {
        /* Selected item is a folder!*/
        return 0;
    }
    else
        return -1;
}
```

To move to the next item, I use:

```
ui->treeView->setCurrentIndex(ui->treeView->currentIndex().sibling(ui->treeView->currentIndex().row()+1, 0));

ui->treeView->selectionModel()->select(ui->treeView->currentIndex(), QItemSelectionModel::ClearAndSelect | QItemSelectionModel::Rows);
```

Back to the original questions, any help towards:

- determining if a selected item is an expanded or non-expanded folder
- easily navigating through items (next item function, and previous item function) without having distinct between sibling, parent, or child functions

is greately appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Documentation has a function "isExpanded", just pass in the modelindex.

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#isExpanded

For the navigation you can use `indexAbove` and `indexBelow` functions. documentation links are given below

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#indexAbove

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreeview.html#indexBelow

Comment: Thanks. I missed that out